# A new monty hall problem

Tags: probability, monty-hall

could someone help me to solve this question with the use of bayes theorem?

What would be the optimal strategy and its probability to win an item of the greatest value if the Monty Hall problem was changed such that:

1. The host will always open a door without the car  (He knows where the car is at)
   a.  The player will be able to ask the host to open a maximum of 3 doors, the however, he is not allowed to switch to the opened door(s).
2. The gameshow will include 10 doors
3. Each door contains an item of value, an increasing value, from a $1 coin to a car
4. The player will be given an opportunity to switch to an unopened door

If required (in the event the question does not work), can someone include a way to make it work? Thanks!

EDIT 1: Monty does not know the value of each door, only the door that contains the car. The contestant aims to walk away with the highest possible value, hence does not necessarily mean he has to walk away with the car prize (IE highest possible prize value)

Comment: The problem seems incomplete.  What rule does Monty follow in opening doors?  Does he know the value of each door?  Does he always open the least valuable?  Does he choose uniformly at random between all the non-car options?  Some other rule?

Comment: And what is the contestant trying to optimize?  The probability of getting the car?  The expected value of the prize they eventually do get?  Something else?  I think if you write the details of the problem out clearly, the optimal strategy should become visible.

Comment: @lulu I see, will it work if the problem states that Monty does not know the value of each of the doors, only where the car is, hence he may open the second most valauble or least valauble door? Also, the contestant is trying to obtain the best possible value in the game, not necessarily being the car. If it does, how should I solve it?

Comment: You can set any rules you want, so long as they are clear.  Also, you haven't even given the values of the prizes.  It clearly makes a huge difference if the second highest is $\$5$ or if it is $\$20K$.  And you need a numerical value for the car, so that  two values can be compared.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the player should always ask that 3 doors be opened.  Assume, without loss of generality that doors 1-3 are opened and that the player chose door 4.  Then, **if** the player was only interested in winning the car, then the player should always switch to any one of the 6 remaining doors (doors 5 thru 10).  Have I understood the problem correctly?

Comment: Based on my previous comment, note that the probability of the car being behind door 4 is **unchanged**, with doors 1 thru 3 being shown.  That is, it remains at $~(1/10).~$  Thus, assuming that the player switches to (for example) door 5, the player's new chance of winning the car is $~\displaystyle \frac{9}{10} \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{3}{20}.$

Comment: @user2661923  Not necessarily.  Say the car is worth $20K$ and the second highest prize is worth $17K$.  Then you'd be happy with the $17$ and you risk losing that option if Monty happens to expose that door.  The prize structure matters a lot here.  Granted that the OP is quite vague on the details.

Comment: @lulu Based on what you said, i gave the rewards a value number
Coin $1
Hat $10
Shirt $20
Jacket $30
Skateboard $50
Bike $200
Phone $500
Tablet $1000
Motorcycle $1500
Car $2000

From here, it would be easier to determine whether the player should swap, so how should i carry forward?
apologies, I am still very unsure on how to carry on with the problem, Many thanks!

Comment: I suggest:  Just assign numerical values, the specific objects don't help with the math.  I think the problem statement is now clear.  You should start by figuring out the value of seeing the first open door.  What's the expected value at the start (easily computed)?  What is the expected value after seeing the first door (you'll need to sum over the cases). Keep in mind that, with three separate options, there are a lot of possible paths so the computation might need to be automated.

Comment: Note:  you will also need to settle on a strategy.  I would think that, as with the classical Monty Hall Problem, one should always switch, but that should be checked.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to simulate the problem first.  As a practical matter, these sort of problems (with multiply branched scenarios) are often handled by simulation rather than by closed form analytic means.  In any case, the simulation should give you an extremely good idea of the true probabilities.

Comment: For the simulation:  I first suggest adopting the simplest strategy, namely "have Monty open three doors and then switch to an unopened one, regardless of what you see."  There are $\binom 93=84$ possibilities for what Monty will show you so you can even do this computation explicitly (though it is tedious).  This strategy may or may not be optimal but it is certainly a good candidate and it's comparatively easier to work with.

Comment: @lulu That is why I qualified my first comment by: "...if the player was only interested in winning the car...".